# JSON Schema v4 "required" in nested object

Tags: json, jsonschema

I tried searching, but I'm not quite sure how to put this in words! The point of confusion is how "required" works in JSON schema v4 when there are **nested key values with the *same name***.

For example, this schema:

```
{
    "Root": {
        "type": ["array", "null"],
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "LevelOne": {
                    "required": ["id", "name", "LevelOneRepeat"],
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                        },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                        },
                    "LevelOneRepeat": {
                        "type": ["array", "null"],
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "required": ["id", "name"],
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                    },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside LevelOne, I have a required for "id", "name", and "LevelOneRepeat". However, inside LevelOneRepeat, I also have a required for "id" and "name".

Does required only check for elements in the same level, or also all child elements? Do I need to include the required inside LevelOneRepeat if the key values required (same name) are already listed in the level above?

I tested my JSON with my schema, but I might've messed up my code somewhere as no required are working anymore.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your schema that is probably what has led to your confusion about how `required` works.

Here is the corrected schema.

```
{
    "type": ["array", "null"],
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "LevelOne": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "id": { "type": "string" },
                    "name": { "type": "string" },
                    "LevelOneRepeat": {
                        "type": ["array", "null"],
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "id": { "type": "string" },
                                "name": { "type": "string" }
                            },
                            "required": ["id", "name"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "required": ["id", "name", "LevelOneRepeat"],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is with the way you define nested objects.  The value of each property must be a schema.  See how I changed the `LevelOne` definition to see how to correctly define a nested object.

The second problem is that have the `required` keyword in the wrong place.  It should be on the same level as the `properties` keyword, not nested within the `properties` object.  This is why your `required` constraints weren't working.  See how I changed the `LevelOne` and `LevelOneRepeat` definitions.

Once you fix these problems, hopefully it should be more clear that the `required` keyword only applies to the schema it is defined in.  It does not apply to any parent or child schema.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` in `LevelOne` and `LevelOneRepeat` are only coincidentally related. They have to be independently specified as `required`.